# How to update rows in datagridview dynamically in C# windows application just like Add to Cart in Asp.net Web application without using database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am jitendra kumar working on a Inventory Management System and we have code to add a row in my dataGridview in windows application using list filed now

I want to update row in dataGridview  just like Add to Cart option in Web Application project, please anyone can give some idea to solve this problem.

Thanks

below is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace SIMS1
{

public partial class Sales : Form
{
DataTable dt;
List<field> data = null; decimal Total = 0;
int Invoiceid,qty;
decimal unitprize,Total_amount;
public Sales()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    binddgvstock();

}

private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    data = new List<field>();
    string invoiceno = txt_invoiceno.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceno))
    {

        string productname = txt_productname.Text;
        decimal unitprize = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_unitprize.Text);
        int Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txt_qty.Text);
        decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_totalamount.Text);
        field f = new field();
        f.ProductName = productname;
        f.UnitPrize = unitprize;
        f.Quantity = Quantity;
        f.TotalAmount = total;
        data.Add(f);


        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToList();

    }
    else
    {
        string productname = txt_productname.Text;
        decimal unitprize = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_unitprize.Text);
        int Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txt_qty.Text);
        decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_totalamount.Text);
        field f = new field();
        f.ProductName = productname;
        f.UnitPrize = unitprize;
        f.Quantity = Quantity;
        f.TotalAmount = total;
        data.Add(f);

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToList();

    }

    txt_productname.Text = "";
    txt_unitprize.Text = "";
    txt_qty.Text = "";
    txt_totalamount.Text = "";

    }
 }
 [Serializable]
 public class field
 {

    public int InvoiceId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string InvoiceNo
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string CustomerId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string CustomerName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string ProductName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal UnitPrize
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Quantity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal DISC
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal TotalAmount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public decimal Total
    {
        get;
        set;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's quite easy actually,first off you need to move these lines out below the if-else block since it's a needless repeitition

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToList();
```

Then replace the final line to:

```
var dt=dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
dt.Rows.Add(data.ToArray());
```

Assumming that your datasource is not null that is

Comment: how if we want to update only Quantity in a particular row

Comment: then you must find the row after that use the same technique above replace the final line with `dt.Rows[Searchrow][Column name]= some value ;'

Comment: I unable to understand please provide some example or code it's humble request to you